# What would happen if we always built new homes to keep the house prices stable?

Tags: macroeconomics, housing

What would happen if the government passed a law to always keep on building new houses so the housing market never appreciated? What would be the economic impacts of this?

Currently housing is in limited supply which causes house prices to go up. People don't want to miss out because they believe right now is the time a particular house will be at its cheapest; which further acts as a driving force to push prices up. On the contrary, if housing market never appreciated, people will not view real estate as a good investment which will cause prices to fall further. Which is important because real estate should never be viewed as an investment asset. This is because unlike other investment instruments, houses do one important job - that is to provide roof over people's head.